# Android: Need help, trying to parse a HTML page using JSoup parser

Tags: android

Here is the code so far I am trying but it is showing me error:

```
URL url = null;
try {
    url = new URL("http://wap.nastabuss.se/its4wap/QueryForm.aspx?hpl=Teleborg+C+(V%C3%A4xj%C3%B6)");
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("1");
Document doc = null;
try {
    System.out.println("2");
    doc = Jsoup.parse(url, 3000);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("3");
Element table = doc.select("table[title=Avgångar:]").first();
System.out.println("4");
Iterator<Element> it = table.select("td").iterator();

//we know the third td element is where we wanna start so we call .next twice
it.next();
it.next();
while(it.hasNext()){
  // do what ever you want with the td element here
System.out.println(it.next());
  //iterate three times to get to the next td you want. checking after the first
  // one to make sure
  // we're not at the end of the table.
  it.next();
  if(!it.hasNext()){ 
    break;
  }
  it.next();
  it.next();
}
```

It prints `System.out.println("3");`

then it stops in this line

`Element table = doc.select("table[title=Avgångar:]").first();`

How can i solve this problem,

Thanks

Comment: whats the worst thing is I cant even print anything whatever, I would really appreciate if someone could have helped me just to print something then i will try my best to specify my query.

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: well, as i told it goes till this line System.out.println("3"); then it stucks and in logcat it says java.lang.nullpointerexception

my question is does this JSoup works for android as well???

Comment: JSoup works fine on Android. What exactly do the line in your logcat say about the nulpointerexception

Comment: is there anything which i have to put in Manifest.xml something, bc it is saying unbale to start activity ComonentInfo....NullPointerException

Comment: it says, 
AndroidRuntime FATAL EXCEPTION: main
AndroidRuntime java.lang.RunTimeException:Unable to start Activity ComponentInfo{com.luli...}

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the website you're trying to parse the HTML from has an error and doesn't have any tables on it. This is what's causing the null pointer exception. `doc.select("table[title=Avgångar:]")` isn't returning an element and then you're trying to call a method on it. To prevent this error from happening again, you could do something like this:

```
Elements foundTables = doc.select("table[title=Avgångar:]");
Element table = null;
if(!foundTables.isEmpty()){
  table = tables.first();
}
```

Now, if any table was found, the `table` variable won't be null. You'll just have to alter the code to adapt in case no tables are found.

Comment: Yeah you are right Kurtis, now there is not buss which comes to university :P, its too late and since the website is generating table automatically whenever there is a nextbuss.
I will try it later, or with any other site


btw thanks from ur support, u are really helpful.

Comment: i tried this site http://www.nseindia.com/content/equities/niftysparks.htm and i changed to Element table = doc.select("table[class=niftyd]").first();
Iterator<Element> it = table.select("td[width=65]").iterator();

Still the same problem :S

Comment: at least i shouldnt have here any problem :P, is it working for u this example??? where is my mistake i am wondering.

Comment: @SamuelLund, You're welcome. If you find my answer helpful, please vote it up and/or accept it. I've modified my answer to help expand on dealing with the null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking the result of `doc.select()` before calling `.first()`. If there are no elements in the document that match the specified query, `doc.select()` could return null. Then you are calling `.first()` on a null pointer which, of course, will throw an exception. There is no `table` tag with the title you have specified in the document that you are using in your example. So, the result is not surprising.

Comment: I tried to get the doc.select() before calling the .first but still I get some errors. Can you please tell me exactly what is the problem. or it might help me a lot if u would have writen me some code.